# Display CollectionVIew in TableVIew headerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Adding a `UICollectionview` inside cell header.

I need to add a `UICollectionView` to the `headerview` of the `UITableViewController`.

My code so far in the tableview controller:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SectionHeader";

    MyTableViewCell *headerView = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    return headerView;

}
```

2.)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(MyTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {




}
```

3.)

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return 3;

}
```

4.)

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

}
```

It only displays a black box of the `UICollectionView` on the `headerview` of the table. No Collection View cells are displayed. How can i get this done ?

The storyboard:

[image]

UPDATE

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    // Initialization code

}



- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];



    // Configure the view for the selected state

    self.cv.delegate=self;

    self.cv.dataSource=self;

}







#pragma mark -

#pragma mark - collection view delegate methods



- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return 5;

}



- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell3";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    if (indexPath.row == 0){

        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    } else {

        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

    }



    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Does your `MyTableViewCell`'s `UICollectionView` has `delegate` and `datasource` set?

Comment: Yes, i set it inside `viewForHeaderInSection `

Comment: This might help you to setup your infrastructure: https://github.com/ashfurrow/AFTabledCollectionView

Comment: Can you post your `MyTableViewCell`'s .h and .m code?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: `UITableView header` and `section header` are not the same things. The first one you may set via `tableView setTableHeaderView:`, the second one you handle via delegate methods. As they do act differently, you should differ it and tell which one you want to have. All the time you're talking about header, then you're setting section header - are you sure you want to have section header or you don't know about table headers?

Comment: I am using `viewForHeaderInSection`